# How do i find the combination of strings in a given list that add up to a certain string (without external libraries)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, combinations

if the string to be formed is 'abcde' and the input list is `['abc', 'd', 'ac', 'ab', 'e', 'abcd']`
the different ways to form string 'abcde' will be

(1) `'abc'+'d'+'e'`

(2) `'abcd'+'e'`

And thus the answer is 2.

How do i approach this problem?

My progress so far ;_;

```
character1 = input()
n = int(input())    # number of allowed inputs for list
list1 = [input() for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: First try to find if you have `abcde` in the list. If not, then start chunking and seeing if the combinations of those form the string `abcde`

Comment: yea, but that requires the use of combinations right, I cannot use itertools as this is supposed to be solved without external libraries.
If you have a way, pls elaborate

Comment: Disinclined to exertion Dude: The documentation for [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) shows what it's equivalent to.

Comment: I strongly recommend using itertools.combinations(). Reinventing that wheel is a very lengthy program. You can try to do it but it will be a lengthy code and you will need to create and check for a lot of combinations

Comment: this is a question in the cses problem set.. I don't think we can import libraries in the submitted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
d, s = ['abc', 'd', 'ac', 'ab', 'e', 'abcd'], 'abcde'
def get_combos(d, c = []):
  if ''.join(c) == s:
     yield c
  else:
     for i in d:
        if s.startswith(''.join(c)+i):
           yield from get_combos(d, c+[i])

print(list(get_combos(d)))
```

Output:

```
[['abc', 'd', 'e'], ['abcd', 'e']]
```